# Obtain column names from query using wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

When using `select * from dbo.myTable`, is there a way with a join or shortcut to get the column names represented from the wildcard?

Looking for a shorthand use so I don't have to type out 80 column names.

Thanks!

Comment: There is if you use ColdFusion.

Comment: Select * from mytable where 1=0 and copy the output with column headers?

Comment: No, really want the column names to be in the query in place of the *....

Comment: The quickest way to do this is to type them out.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output you want? Couldn't you just use Information_Schema?

Answer (score 1):

I use SQLComplete for this..

https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/

Not quite what you want, but it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

here is a script that will work on sql server(assuming that is your vendor as you have dbo in your example)

```
declare @table as varchar(max) = 'spt_monitor' -- replace this with your table

select 'select ' +  stuff((SELECT ', ' + column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = @table for xml path('')),1,1,'')  + ' from ' + @table
```

copy and paste the output and enjoy.

Comment: This works!  I was hoping there was a join or shortcut so I wouldn't have to copy/paste results to get it, but I can use this.  Thanks!

Comment: please mark it as an answer then if it was helpful.